# Mounting HDFS directory

Tags: ubuntu, hdfs, mount

Can I mount HDFS directory (configured in Ubuntu) to a drive in Windows server ?

After mapping e.g H:\ ---> \home\user1\HDFSCreatedDir , would like to read, write and move/copy files using normal Java IO package API's.

Comment: You could possibly do it with Samba, but it's off-topic here. Ask on [unix.se]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, HDFS directory can be mounted in Windows and Linux. You can use one of the tools below:

- contrib/fuse-dfs is built on fuse, some C glue, libhdfs and the hadoop-dev.jar
- fuse-j-hdfs is built on fuse, fuse for java, and the hadoop-dev.jar
- hdfs-fuse - a google code project is very similar to contrib/fuse-dfs
- webdav - hdfs exposed as a webdav resource
- mapR - contains a closed source hdfs compatible file system that supports read/write NFS access
- HDFS NFS Proxy - exports HDFS as NFS without use of fuse. Supports Kerberos and re-orders writes so they are written to hdfs sequentially.
- native-hdfs-fuse - a FUSE implementation in C that supports random writes
  While not complete filesystem implementations (FUSE or otherwise), the following projects could be useful when building one
- hadoofus - an implementation of the libhdfs API in C for hadoop 0.20.203 to 1.0.3

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will try above options.