# Ingesting data files into HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have terabyte of CSV files which I need to ingest into HDFS, files are residing on application server I can FTP data on edge node and use any of below methods .

```
HDFS CLI (-put)
Mounting HDFS
Using ETL tools
```

I was wondering which method will be good to use in terms of performance
Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

I can remember that I have faced with similar situation in one of my previous projects. We have followed the approach of mounting HDFS. This will allow the users to transfer files easily from the local system. I have found the below links which might help you.

[mounting hdfs - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966414/mounting-hdfs-directory)

[HDFS NFS Gateway](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.3.9/bk_user-guide/content/user-guide-hdfs-nfs.html)

Comment: It's about 5TB of data we have used.